# My DoSomething lambda task does not return a value

Tags: vb.net, lambda, delegates, task

This snippet does not compile. How to properly use the lambda function?

I have tried sending an integer to the function in various places. It does not return a proper value.

I would like the DoSomething routine to select various possible subtasks for a parallel task application.

I have been trying to follow examples of setting up tasks:

```
 Dim action As Action(Of Object)
        action = Sub(obj As Object)
                     MessageBox.Show("Task manager " + vbCrLf +
                     "Current ID " + Task.CurrentId.ToString + vbCrLf + "Object " + obj.ToString + vbCrLf + "Thread ID " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString)
             End Sub
    Dim t1 As New Task(action, "Control 1")
    Dim t3 As New Task(action, "Control 2")
    Dim t4 As New Task(action, "Control 3")

    t1.Start()
    t1.Wait()

    t3.Start()
    t3.Wait()

    t4.Start()
    t4.Wait()

    Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, "Control 4")

    Dim t5 = Function(ctr As Integer) ctr + 2
    MessageBox.Show("Answer " + t5(6).ToString)
```

These work, but the last effort to make a function call is failing.

```
 Dim DoSomething As Action(Of Integer)
        DoSomething = Function(index As Integer)
                          Select Case index
                              Case 0
                                  Return "FirstName"
                              Case 1
                                  Return "LastName"
                              Case 2
                                  Return "CompanyName"
                              Case Else
                                  Return "LastName"
                          End Select
                      End Function


    If DoSomething(1).ToString = "FirstName" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world")
    End If
```

I expect a match in the case statement, but the return value is nonexistent, "function does not return a value" or returns the path of the subroutine call.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and it's basically never a good idea to use it without explicitly providing a scheduler.  The defaults are poorly chosen and lead to surprising behavior.  If you don't want to customize, just use `Task.Run`.  Also see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want DoSomething to return a `String` value, it must be defined as a `Func(Of Integer, String)`.  As an `Action(Of Integer)` it is treated like a subroutine.

```
    Dim DoSomething As Func(Of Integer, String)
    DoSomething = Function(index As Integer)
                      Select Case index
                          Case 0
                              Return "FirstName"
                          Case 1
                              Return "LastName"
                          Case 2
                              Return "CompanyName"
                          Case Else
                              Return "LastName"
                      End Select
                  End Function
```

Note that it won't show the Hello World message box because passing 1 will yield "LastName".

This would be more appropriate of a way to write the value of DoSomething if it was never meant to return a string and was supposed to truly be an Action(of Integer):

```
    Dim DoSomethingAsAction As Action(Of Integer)
    DoSomethingAsAction = Sub(index As Integer)
                              Select Case index
                                  Case 0
                                      MsgBox("Hello World!")
                              End Select
                          End Sub

    DoSomethingAsAction.Invoke(0)
```